# Angularjs rename items in an array

Tags: angularjs, arrays

Adding items from one array to a new array using:

```
   $scope.listItems = [];
   $scope.addToList = function(item) {
     $scope.listItems.push(item);
     console.log($scope.listItems);
  };

<tr ng-repeat="x in data">
  <td><{{ x.id }}</td>
  <td><button type="button" ng-click="addToList(x.id)">Add to</button></td>
</tr>
```

Then printing the new array:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in listItems">
   <td>{{item.id}}</td>
</tr>
```

Would it be possible to change the attribute names of the new listItems array using user input?

Comment: Why would it not be possible?

Comment: Is the **cityName** anything from data that you're iterating through ng-repeat ? anything like **x.cityName** ?

Comment: Ah forgott to change that one  to x.id, shortened the code posted a bit to make it simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure its possible. But not the way your code is written. You need to pass the object to the function, not the id.

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in data">
  <td>{{ x.id }}</td>
  <td><input type="text" ng-model="newVal"/></td> <!--this property can be changed by user-->
  <td><button type="button" ng-click="addToList(x, newVal)">Add to</button></td>
</tr>
```

and in the controller function:

```
  $scope.addToList = function(item, newVal) {
     var newItem = item;
     newItem.id =  newVal;
     $scope.listItems.push(item);
     console.log($scope.listItems);
  };
```

Comment: Was a misstake on my end, the real question was if it would be possible to change attribute names in the new listItems array through user input, like a text input field or something?

Comment: property names or property values? see above for setting property values

Comment: values like id.

Comment: and the original array should stay the same?

Comment: yes, thats the whole idea of creating the new array

Answer (score 0):

You could definitely do that, But for that you need to pass in the object in itself not x.id.

Here is a sample working solution.

```js
var app = angular.module("sampleApp", []);

app.controller("sampleController", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.data = [{
      id: "City-1"
    }, {
      id: "City-2"
    }, {
      id: "City-3"
    }, {
      id: "City-4"
    }, {
      id: "City-5"
    }];

    $scope.listItems = [];
    $scope.addToList = function(item) {
      $scope.listItems.push(item);
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="sampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="sampleController">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="x in data">
        <td>
          {{ x.id }}</td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" ng-click="addToList(x)">Add to</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    New List:
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in listItems track by $index">
        <td>
          {{ item.id }}</td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" ng-click="addToList(x)">Add to</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```